# Dropzone js parallel upload causes problems in backend

Tags: php, validation, parallel-processing, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm currently building a system, where users can upload images to their ads. Each ad can have 8 images associated. One of those images become the primary image, which is display in search results and so on.
When I upload multiple images using parallel and count the already existing records in db, to make sure that the limit aren't reached, things get weird.
Because all images hit the server at the same time, they all passes the check to make sure, that you only upload 8 images and they are all uploaded suddenly.
Everything works fine, if the user just upload one image at a time.

I don't know how to come along this bug.
What is best practice ?

I'm using Laravel 5, just in case...

Thanks!

```
public function store(UploadAdImageRequest $request, $id)
{
    $ad = $this->adRepo->getWithImages($id);

    $this->imageRepo->hasSpace($ad);

    $image = $this->imageRepo->upload($request->file('image')->getRealPath(), $ad);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Christan.  Please make sure you have read the [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.  Also, please post some of your code.  No one will be able to help you unless they can see your code.

Comment: The same problem. But I am not using db, just file system. All files are being uploaded in parallel mode, so there can be  the situation when I count number of existing files in directory is the same for two files, and one rewrite another.